# Why is this react handleChange not working? Trying to handle a change received by props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field in react, whose value is initially set by a props received by the component

```
<EditUserModal 
   show={this.state.showModal} 
   close={this.closeModal} 
   userId={this.state.rowId} 
   email={this.state.selectedMail}
/>
```

As you can see it received the value email, and inside the component I can see the valu changing properly

```
<div class="form-group emailgroup">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Change Email Address</label>
  <input 
    type="email"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="name@example.com"
    value={this.props.email}
    onChange={this.handleChange} 
  />
</div>
```

Problem is, that I add a handleChange event, to be able to modify that input, but it doesnt modify the email, I suppose that its because I should change the props in the parent component, but I dont understand how to do it. Currently my handleChange function looks like this.

```
handleChange = (evt) => {
  this.setState({
    email: evt.target.value
  });
}
```

And this is the initial state fo the component

```
this.state = {
  email : ""
};
```

Obviously since im not calling the state, but the props to asign the value of the field, it doesnt change. But ive tried....

```
this.state = {
  email : props.email
};
```

And it lets me change it this way, but the problem is that it will render nothing initially in the input value.

Comment: you can use componentDidMount for assign your props.email value to state.email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't assign your props to state, instead call your function from parent and pass state value to child component.

you can refer this for better understanding of parent to child data flow.

[How to change the state of a child component from its parent in React](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-changing-state-of-child-component-from-parent-8ab547436271/)

Answer (score -1):

You are passing the wrong value into the component. Current you have this:

```
email={this.state.selectedEmail}
```

But when you look at what you're setting in the parent component, it's not 'selectedEmail' but 'email'. Changing the property should fix it:

```
email={this.state.email}
```

Then the correct value should be worked on.